# How to use paramterized AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) with viewBinding?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I know how to use paramterized Fragment(R.layout.fragment_dummy), and bind its view with viewBinding and use it. As code shown below
[image: Use of Paramterized Fragment]

But I don't know how I can use parametrized activity in similar way.

Answer (score 0):

binding should happen in `onCreateView`, returning then `binding.root`

```
private var someBinding: SomeBinding? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    someBinding = SomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    return someBinding!!.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    someBinding = null
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

in `Activity` you are using binding in `onCreate` method and use `setContentView(binding.root)`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = SomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
```

you don't have to keep reference to `binding` in `Activity` (as it isn't mandatory to release/clean it up when layout host gets destroyed), but it may be useful later for setting `View`s attributes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here an generate code from android studio itself.

For activity

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
```

For Fragment

```
private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {

    _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

By access your view

```
binding.textView
```

Comment: I know how to use in case of Fragment, I am asking about how we can use simpliar  way in case of activty. And Please tell me  what is usage of AppCompatActivity(R.laout.activity_main), and how I can use with viewBinding.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar ohhh my bad. i will drop the update.

Answer (score 0):

For Fragment with ViewBinding it is not Possible parameteried but you can use like below

```
 class DemoFragment : Fragment() {
    private var mBinding: FragmentDemoBinding? = null;

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        mBinding = FragmentDemoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return mBinding?.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }
}
```